# INSERT INTO from a very large SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have the following INSERT :

```
INSERT INTO "Positions" 
(SELECT source_id, (r1.cd).x, (r1.cd).y, (r1.cd).z FROM 
  (SELECT source_id, stars_icrs2gcrs(ra, "dec", r_est) AS cd
   FROM "StarsWithDistance"
   )
 AS r1);
```

The SELECT returns about 1.3 billion rows. If I put a LIMIT clause it works, the Positions table is updated. So the INSERT as written works. But if I let it go on all the rows, it complete successfully however the Positions table is empty.

What would be the best / most elegant way to handle this kind of INSERT? I don't really care about performance here, this INSERT will be executed once and never again after. Obviously I don't want it to takes weeks! But a day is not a problem. As written right now it takes 3 hours.

Comment: Try writing function or do statement and insert rows with smaller portions.

Comment: I know SQL but I'm far from being an expert. I essentially do single line statements. How would you break this into smaller bits?

Comment: "it complete successfully however the Positions table is empty." doesn't sound likely to me. I can believe it failed to populate the table, but not that it did so without reporting an error.

Comment: Well it happened. More than once.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to commit?

Comment: Autocommit is enabled.

Comment: And what is this `stars_icrs2gcrs(ra, "dec", r_est)` function? Why doesittakea double quoted argument?  Is "dec" a column in one of your tables (`"StarsWithDistance"`) ?

Comment: The function transform from one coordinate system to another. PostgreSQL in some generated SQL has put Dec, which is indeed a column, between quotes. I guess it's also a reserved word. So I've used the same. But the function doesn't change anything to my problem. Working with a limited numbers of lines works, all of them doesn't. Although postgres tells me it is successful in both cases.

Comment: I decided to try out Materialized View instead. We'll see out it goes.

Comment: Worked with materialized view. Was able to add the indexes I needed as well.